# What kind of Texture map is it and how to use it?

Tags: texturing, shaders

It seems like these textures are needed to create dirt, but how do I do this and why do the textures look like this? [image: example image 1 showing texture in question]

[image: example image 2 showing texture in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red, green and yellow colors indicate that this is a UV texture from Unreal Engine 4. You might be able to bake the mask into a PBR texture in UE4, or use a separate RGB node in blender to use this dirt mask texture.